# Not able to remove returns and/or newlines from String in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, newline

The question I am trying to solve requires me to read in a text file and separate all words in a file into different "Token" objects stored in an ArrayList, no spaces or newlines should be stored. The current code:

```
String[] tokenArray = line.split("\\s+");
```

removes all spaces from the string, but I cannot remove new lines/ returns.

I've tried running both these lines SEPARATELY on the line before the .split() method in order to remove new lines and they do not work.

```
line = line.replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "");
line = line.replaceAll("\\R+", "");
```

Here is the entire method.

```
public void tokenizeFile(String filePath) throws IOException
{
    String line = "";
    FileReader file = new FileReader(filePath);
    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(file);
    tokens.clear();
    keywords = 0;
    while((line = read.readLine()) != null)
    {
        String[] tokenArray = line.split("\\s+");
        for(int i = 0; i < tokenArray.length; i++)
        {
            Token newToken = new Token(tokenArray[i]);
            this.tokens.add(newToken);
            keywords++;
        }
    }
    read.close();
}
```

note: keywords is a totally irrelevant private int that the professor wanted to be incremented in the method for each object added to the ArrayList

The contents of the ArrayList are copied into an array of type Token obj: Token[] (professor requirement) and then written to an output text file with each Token object written to a newline. Here are the copy and writing methods.

```
public Token[] getTokenizer()
{
    Token[] tokenList = new Token[tokens.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++)
    {
        tokenList[i] = tokens.get(i);
    }
    return tokenList;
}
public void writeTokens() throws IOException
{
    PrintWriter writer = null;
    try
    {
        Token[] list = getTokenizer();
        writer = new PrintWriter("output.txt");
        for(int i = 0; i < keywords; i++)
        {
            writer.println(list[i]);
        }
        writer.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e + e.getMessage());
    } finally{
        if (writer != null)
        {
            writer.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the contents of the file passed into the method:

```
The cat in the    hat



one fish two fish    red fish   blue    fish
```

This is the contents of the output file (what writeTokens() writes):

```
The
cat
in
the
hat



one
fish
two
fish
red
fish
blue
fish
```

For entire reference:

Token.java

```
public class Token
{
    private String token;

    public String getValue()
    {
        return token;
    }
    public void setValue(String token)
    {
        this.token = token;
    }
    public Token()
    {

    }
    public Token(String s)
    {
        this.token = s;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format(token);
    }
}
```

Tokenizer.java

```
public class Token
{
    private String token;

    public String getValue()
    {
        return token;
    }
    public void setValue(String token)
    {
        this.token = token;
    }
    public Token()
    {

    }
    public Token(String s)
    {
        this.token = s;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format(token);
    }
}
```

Driver.java

```
public class Driver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Tokenizer tokenizer = new Tokenizer();
            tokenizer.tokenizeFile("input.txt");
            tokenizer.writeTokens();
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: updates in reply to comments.

using:

```
String[] tokenArray = line.split("\\R");
```

outputs:

```
The cat in the    hat



one fish two fish    red fish   blue    fish
```

using:

```
String[] tokenArray = line.split("(\\W+)");
```

yields:

```
cat
in
the
hat



one
fish
two
fish
red
fish
blue
fish
```

My IDE is vs Code and I am compiling using the integrated terminal.

```
bash-3.2$ javac Driver.java
bash-3.2$ java Driver
bash-3.2$ cat output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the regular expression

```java
String[] tokens = line.split("(\\W+)");
```

UPD:
Using jshell I got this output:

```
jshell> String fileContents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("input")));
fileContents ==> "The cat in the      hat\n\none fish two fish    red fish   blue    fish\n"

jshell> fileContents.split("(\\W+)");
$2 ==> String[13] { "The", "cat", "in", "the", "hat", "one", "fish", "two", "fish", "red", "fish", "blue", "fish" }
```

Comment: just tried re compiling with that regex and it still produces the same output.

Comment: I really have no idea why; I'm getting right output with this regexp, updated the answer

Comment: I do not understand either, I spent hours looking at similar problems and answers, nothing seems to remove the newlines, even when using a specific regex that removes newlines.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier than it seems.

The `split("\\s+")` gives an array on splitting of whitespace: spaces and tabs.
One problem with that is that a line might start or end with whitespace, so giving also the empty string `""`.

For the new lines: there are many line separators, `\r`, `r\n`, `\n`, NEL (`\u0085`). For that in regex the `"\\R"` was introduced.

However `readLine()` intelligently yields the line *without* the line separator.
So that takes care of everything.

Comment: I tried the regex "\\R" and "\\R+" in the .split() method and they produced incorrect outputs. Perhaps I interpreted your answer incorrectly.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear: reeadLine strips newline character sequences, so `line` needs not to be split on newlines.